# Change what a value/reference type "points" to

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, pass-by-reference, subroutine

How can I change what a value/reference type "points" to?

For example, in the following pseudo scenario. I want to save out a value from a routine. WorkRoutine in this situation would do some work then call the lambda expression. Due to ref/out being disallowed in lambdas, I'm using tmp to store the value from the routine, I would like to make saveOut point to that same address/value. And hopefully that value will be kept alive outside of SomeMethod.

```
public void SomeMethod<T> (ref T saveOut)
{
    T tmp;
    WorkRoutine( (value) => tmp = value) ); // ref saveOut can't be used in a lambda
    saveOut = tmp;   
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Is WorkRoutine asynchronous?

Comment: You could say that it will be working on a separate routine.